Is the set of plane-tiling pentagons algebraic?
To explain the title, let me indulge in a little notation: every $n$-gon in the plane can be viewed as a point in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ in the natural way; associate the polygon with points $\langle p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n\rangle$ where e.g. $p_1=(p_{1x}, p_{1y})$ with the point $(p_{1x}, p_{1y}, \ldots, p_{nx}, p_{ny})$. All of the sets I'm talking about here will share a fixed but arbitrary $n$; e.g., the set of triangles, the set of quadrilaterals, etc. Under this identification many sets of $n$-gons are easily seen to be algebraic sets: The condition that no two edges of a polygon cross can be expressed as the intersection over $i, j$ of all the sets of polygons where edges $i$ and $j$ don't cross, and that condition is expressible as a polynomial inequality via the usual procedure of solving for the intersection point of two lines. Similarly, the set of convex $n$-gons is algebraic; the additional condition that point $p_{i+1}$ lies on the 'right' side of the line $\overline{p_{i-1}p_i}$ is easily expressible algebraically.
Given this and given some known classical results, it can be shown that the set of all convex $n$-gons that tile the plane is algebraic for each $n$: if $n\geq 7$ then there are none, if $n\leq 4$ then every $n$-gon does, and for $n=5$ and $n=6$ we have the wonderful collaborative classifications (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling); all of the constraints in these classifications are algebraic and therefore their union is.
I'm curious if this still holds if we drop the 'convex' condition: AFAICT a full classification of (simple) pentagons that tile the plane is still an open problem, but it seems as though it might be possible to show that the set is algebraic even without knowing its full structure. Is anything known about this, either for pentagons or for $n$-gons in the broad?
